# Python AES.MODE_CTR does not decrypt as expected

Tags: python, node.js, pycrypto

I am trying to rewrite a **node.js** decoding function in python

this is the function I am trying to rewrite

```
module.exports.decrypt = function (data, key, iv, hmacKey) {

iv = iv.slice(0, 16)

var decipherer = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ctr', key, iv)

var hmac

if (hmacKey) {
    hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', hmacKey).update(data).digest()
}

return {
    data: decipherer.update(data),
    hmac: hmac
}
}
```

the `key` parameter is generated by `crypto.pbkdf2Sync` function of node's standard library.

What I implemented in python is

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter

def decrypt(data, key, iv, hmac=None):
    iv = iv[:16]
    ctr = Counter.new(128)
    cipher = AES.new(key, mode=AES.MODE_CTR, IV=iv, counter=ctr)
    return cipher.decrypt(data)
```

I provided the python decrypt function the same same data that the js function receives.
since the `data` and `key`, `iv` params that the js function expects are binary buffers, I copied them to the python code as hex strings and then used `binascii.unhexlify` in the python code before passing them to the `ecrypt` python function.

so the arguments that I am providing to both functions are (hex)

```
data 972acf88c5d7
key 129b6e542600889a75ec7659d9dc23df
iv 31323331323331323331323331323331323331323331313233313233313233313233
```

The python function returns gibberish.
can anyone help?

thanks!